# Remove all duplicates on iTunes library

Tags: itunes

I want to remove all duplicates from my library, to consider a duplicate the song must have the same encoding, bits, duration.

Comment: How does "Display Exact Duplicates" not let you clean out songs that meet your criteria?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the default iTunes engine to find duplicates :

> File > Display Duplicates

[image: duplicates]

Or, use a third-party software like [TuneUp](http://www.tuneupmedia.com/) or [TidySongs](http://www.tidysongs.com/about/).

Comment: I remember some one later asked the same question but can't find it, also you trick don't work fine fore me iTunes Display Duplicate worked buggy for me.

Comment: I was also sure someone already posted this question, but I, too,  cannot find it anymore. At least, I'm not crazy ! I know the built-in functionality is a buggy, that's why I added links to 3rd-party softwares.

Comment: Another alternative I can highly recommend: [Dupin](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/dupin.php)

Comment: I was aware of this option, but wanted an automatic way to remove the duplicates

Comment: This approach (at least as of 10.5.1) will not do what the questions asks: songs do not need to have the "same encoding" to be recognized as duplicates.

Comment: Note the use of Display 'Exact' Duplicates: support.apple.com/kb/ht2905 Then filter/compair the duplicates and look by looking at date added, bit rate, and size.

Comment: TidySongs has been discontinued according to their website, and so the link should perhaps be removed from this answer. They recommend that people use Rinse My Music instead: http://www.rinsemymusic.com/

Answer (score 5):

"Show duplicates" been removed from iTunes 11. As we are left with having to use 3rd party apps to remove duplicates now, [Tune Sweeper](http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/tunesweeper/) is the one I use.

Comment: Come on apple, this problem is completely ridiculous and rampant, fix it!!!

Comment: This is not true, it has been moved to "View > Show Duplicate Items / (alt) Show Exact Duplicate Items"

Answer (score 4):

If you enable iTunes Match, duplicates will now be marked with an [icon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31258/what-do-the-various-itunes-match-icons-in-itunes-mean):

[image]

Note however that such files do not need to have the "same encoding" to be recognized as duplicates. Also note that (inconveniently) the file marked by Match as a duplicate (and thus "skipped") may not have the "best" encoding of the duplicated files. For example, you might see this:

[image]

In this case, in order to end up with a single song, managed by Match, with the high bit-rate song on your machine, you will need to delete *both* songs, leaving just the one managed by Match (the first one above)

[image]

and then download the "Purchased" song from iCloud

[image]

Comment: This combined with the existing `Display Exact Duplicates` should help anyone use the existing tools to thin out duplicates that are exact matches.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two more options:
Free - [DupeGuru](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_me/)
Shareware - [iDupe](http://www.woodenbrain.com/products/idupe/idupe.html)

I haven't tried DupeGuru yet, but iDupe worked quite well for me, though I had to batch up my checkin.  First I'd select iTune's buggy "display dupes" and then I'd use that selection to run iDupe on.  This sped things up quite a bit.  I'm interested to see whether DupeGuru improves things by checking audio finger prints.