# How to clean up duplicates in iTunes library?

Tags: itunes

How do I remove duplicate songs from my iTunes library?

Is there an easier way than just <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + Click every other song in the list?

Comment: Here's a duplicate question posted earlier: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/remove-all-duplicates-on-itunes-library/23230#23230

Answer (score 3):

Apple doesn't have anything natively to select duplicate files so, unfortunately, you'll have to resort to a paid solution like [Dupin](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/dupin.php#register) or you could try [Randy's Träume's script](http://randystraeume.blogspot.com/2011/03/cleaning-up-your-itunes-library-on-mac.html).

I haven't used either so I can't vouch for how well they work, but forums I found relating to this problem point to Dupin frequently so that might be your best bet if you don't mind spending a little coin.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes **does** have a way to show duplicate songs, in your library and in playlists.

File > Display Duplicates

Remember that the playlist has to contain more than one track/video/podcast for the "Display Duplicates" option to show.

Comment: Yes we know that this feature exists but the problem is that Apple does not provide an easy way to remove the duplicates. If you sort them by name you with have to command-click each second one in order to remove them. Imagine how it is if you have 2000 duplicates.

Comment: Ah, ok. Didn't understand the question :)

Answer (score 1):

I am very happy with *Corral iTunes Dupes* script, which I downloaded from Doug’s Scripts years ago. It seems to be gone now, but I found a modification [here](http://www.enilnomi.net/cgi-bin/blosxom.cgi/dltext/corralitunesdupes.dl).

[image]

However, it’s a PPC app (pretty old!), which you have to convert to Intel architecture by dragging it to `AppleScript Editor.app` and saving it as Application. You only have to do this once.

Answer (score 0):

Dupin is worth paying for if you are not comfortable working with AppleScripts (which are straightforward in any event)