# What do the various iTunes Match icons in iTunes mean?

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match

Enabling iTunes Match adds a new default column to song lists in iTunes that displays several new icons:

[image][image][image][image][image]

What do each of these icons (as well as no icon at all) mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple's [iTunes Match: Understanding the iCloud Status icons](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4124) KB article explains.

[image]

So, your icons in order are:

1. Available for download
2. Waiting
3. Error
4. Duplicate
5. Ineligible

If you're having problems, take a look at the [Troubleshooting iTunes Match](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4054) article.

Comment: And what does no icon at all mean?

Comment: Does "duplicate" mean that there is another copy on the machine that _has_ been uploaded to the cloud?

Comment: I'm not sure what no icon means, but I believe that Duplicate does mean that there's already a copy in the cloud.

Comment: I think I see what no icon means: the song is on your machine "already" — i.e., it's in the cloud, but is present on the machine too. This can be a bit misleading though as the version "already" on the machine many not be the 256kbps version that's available in the cloud.

Comment: In fact, there seem to be three "versions" of no icon: (1) Matched = iTunes found a match, even though you didn't purchase it through iTunes; (2) Purchased = you purchased this track from iTunes (for both of which, as mentioned, the version in the cloud may be better than the one you have); and (3) Uploaded = with indicates songs that iTunes could not find a match in its database but which you have uploaded to iCloud.