# iTunes Match: What do these symbols mean in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I've noticed that on some compilations I own, the following can be seen:

[image]

According to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31258/what-do-the-various-itunes-match-icons-in-itunes-mean) the two symbols mean "Duplicate" and "Available for Download".

Why would iTunes do this? It appears it's saying the song is not eligible for iTunes Match, but then is offering me to download it (presumably from iTunes Match).

Very confusing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have 2 copies of that song on your local library. One of them was uploaded/matched on iTunes Match and the other wasn't because it is a duplicate. The one with the duplicate icon is the duplicate and the one with the download icon is the one available in iTunes Match.

Comment: But if iTunes knows it's an exact duplicate, why list it twice in the album's tack-listing? :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a duplicate (i.e. on a compilation album for example) try changing the song's title. I put the track number in front of the song title (01, 02 etc). Then iTunes sees it as different track and will let you download it. After downloading you simply change the title back.