# What is the easiest way to find and delete duplicate songs in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, mac, applications, music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove all duplicates on iTunes library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/remove-all-duplicates-on-itunes-library)

A few days ago, I synced all of songs from my iPhone 4s to iTunes. After it finished, I found that some of them have duplicates. I thought maybe I transferred them to iTunes before. Now I want to find and delete them from my iTunes library. What is the easiest way to delete the duplicates? 
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a menu item for this directly in iTunes:

[image]

You may find additional utilities at [Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/).